# Can we have calculus without axiom of choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Do we need axiom of choice for all the theorems studied in basic courses like calculus 1 and linear albgebra? could we build this theory just by using ZF axioms?

Comment: Calculus without the Axiom of Choice is like a fish without a bicycle.

Comment: In proving for example, that an infinite set of points inside a closed segment has an accumulation point. We take a decreasing sequence of segments, $... \subset I_n \subset ...\subset I_2 \subset I_1 $ and CHOOSE a point in each. Don't we need axiom of choice for that?

Comment: Axiom of choice isnt related to calculus from what I know. It is related to the possibility to count different cardinals alef and for some extravagant theorems as the theorem of Tarski-Banach. Maybe in combinatorics/probability take more uses too, not sure.

Comment: Related threads: [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141666/axiom-of-choice-and-calculus), [two](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103743/foundation-for-analysis-without-axiom-of-choice), [three](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730260/proving-there-is-a-sequence-convergent-to-a-limit-point-of-a-set-without-axiom-o), [four](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126010/continuity-and-the-axiom-of-choice), and there are many many more specific ones. I'll close this as a duplicate of the first, since it's rather general.

Comment: I also found this post interesting http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126010/continuity-and-the-axiom-of-choice. Basically, you need some form of AC to get the equivalence between continuity and sequential continuity.

Comment: @Lucian: Not quite. You use the axiom of choice for some basic theorems like the equivalence of continuity at a point (limits vs. $\varepsilon$-$\delta$); **A student:** No, choosing from intervals is easy, just pick a rational number using the fact the rationals are well-orderable (it is a countable set after all).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: The mere fact that the only ones bringing up that notion are almost exclusively set theorists speaks volumes. When was the last time anyone ever heard such questions being *genuinely* asked by someone not in that particular field ? The rest of the $($mathematical$)$ world seems to go on just fine without it.

Comment: @Lucian: I don't know what you are trying to say. Are you saying the only people who use continuity by sequences are set theorists? That just doesn't sound right. I also don't know how many set theorists care about that either. Your comment, in a whole, is quite insulting as a set theorist.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Please don't be upset, because that would make me sad also. And, without denying the theoretical $($objective$)$ importance of axioms $($which is made subjectively stronger in those whose inclinations lie towards the more abstract parts of mathematics$)$, I believe the right word describing the relevance of this axiom is “overrated”. This is my sincere opinion; I do not wish to offend anyone.

Comment: When we are not dealing with set theory, then, we assume that everyone "knows" which assumptions can be used without a proof and which should be proved. But, the whole point in mathemathic is that you can not relay on anything without formal "objective" proof. This is why, I think, at some point, set theory was needed. This kind of "agreement" which I think Lucian is reffering to, must be satteled, I think. This is why I asked this question. I will have a look in the references. Thank you.