# Question about sequence convergent to a limit point and Axiom of (Countable) Choice

Tags: metric-spaces, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/730260/802314) about how the Axiom of Countable Choice is both necessary and sufficient to show the following:

> If a point $a$ in a metric space $X$ is a limit point of $A\subseteq X$, then there is a sequence of points in $A-\{a\}$ converging to $a$.

Is the Axiom of Countable Choice also enough if we require that the sequence be a sequence of distinct points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  If $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $A-\{a\}$ converging to $a$, just let $(b_m)$ be the sequence obtained from $(a_n)$ by removing duplicates (so $b_m$ is the $m$th distinct term of $(a_n)$).  Then $(b_m)$ still converges to $a$, since it is a subsequence of $(a_n)$.